# Confidence bounds on mean of a limited normal distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, mean

Suppose we are sampling from an underlying normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, i.e $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. However, whenever we find a sample value that is greater than some pre-defined threshold $t_m$, we set that sample value equal to $t_m$. For example, if we are sampling from $\mathcal{N}(8,4)$ and the first 6 samples were $s_1 = \{10.18, 10.21, 6.27, 8.15, 5.57, 5.77\}$, then with $t_m = 10$, we would have the samples  $s_2 = \{10, 10, 6.27, 8.15, 5.57, 5.77\}$. If I am correct, then elements in $s_2$ are samples from a '*limited normal distribution*', whose cumulative distribution function is given as:
$$
F(t) = \left\{ \begin{array} {cc}
\Phi\left(\dfrac{t-\mu}{\sigma}\right) & t < t_m \\
1 & t \geq t_m
\end{array} \right.
$$
where $\Phi()$ is the cdf of standard normal distribution.

I am trying to estimate the $(1-\alpha)\times100\%$ confidence interval for the mean of the limited normal distribution. Note that in the problem that I am trying to solve, I don't know beforehand the mean and variance of the underlying normal distribution, and its very time-consuming to find them. Thus any technique that involves using the mean and variance of the underlying normal (as suggested in the [1]) is not useful for me. I am looking for a method that uses mostly the collected samples to give a confidence bound of how close the *sample mean* is to the *true mean*.

Some notes:

- I have tried Chebyshev's inequality but its not a very tight bound.
- Can I somehow use confidence interval of normal distribution with sample mean and variance of the *limited* normal distribution?

***References***

[1] Ionut Bebu, Thomas Mathew, Confidence intervals for limited moments and truncated moments in normal and lognormal models, Statistics & Probability Letters, Volume 79, Issue 3, 1 February 2009, Pages 375-380, ISSN 0167-7152, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.spl.2008.09.006.

Comment: (1) The factor of $1/\sqrt{2}$ does not belong in the expression of $F$. (2) Is $t_m$ known to you? (3) If so, this is *identical* to the problem of estimation with right-censoring at $t_m$.  Solutions can be found by searching our site. One subtlety to be aware of is that if you truly wish to estimate the mean, *which is not the same as $\mu$*, then you are actually estimating a linear combination of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: (1) Thanks for pointing it out, corrected. (2) $t_m$ is known to me beforehand. (3) 'censoring' was the key term which I guess I was missing. I will look into it more and update. Finally, can you please elaborate what do you mean when you say 'mean is not the same as $\mu$'?

Comment: whuber is explaining that the mean of the right-censored variable is not $\mu$, That would be the mean of the unobserved "uncensored" variable that notionally underlies it.